# Left Join row using pairing id table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014, and trying to do a difficult left join operation.

My structure looks like this:

**Items Table**

```
itemID    attribute1     attribute2

1         blue           small
2         green          large
3         brown          medium
4         yellow         extra small
5         orange         extra large
```

**ItemPairs Table**

```
itemPairID   firstItemID   secondItemID

1            2              4
2            1              3
```

What I'm trying to do is perform a select from the `items` table while left joining the paired row from the `items` table in order to get attributes from that paired item as well.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
SELECT attribute1, attribute2, ip.firstitemid, ip.seconditemid
FROM items
LEFT JOIN
    itempairs ip on items.itemid = ip.firstitemid or items.itemid = ip.seconditemid
WHERE itemid = '1'
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: `ip.itemid` should be `items.itemid`

Comment: thanks, added some sample data and fixed `items.itemid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double join:

```
select i1.*, i2.*
from itempairs ip 
inner join items i1 on i1.itemid = ip.firstitemid
inner join items i2 on i2.itemid = ip.seconditemid
```

If you want also the unpaired items:

```
select i1.*, i2.*
from itempairs ip 
inner join items i1 on i1.itemid = ip.firstitemid
inner join items i2 on i2.itemid = ip.seconditemid
union
select i.*, null, null, null
from items i
where i.itemid not in (
  select firstitemid from itempairs
  union
  select seconditemid from itempairs
)
```

If you want only a specific pair:

```
select i1.*, i2.*
from itempairs ip 
inner join items i1 on i1.itemid = ip.firstitemid
inner join items i2 on i2.itemid = ip.seconditemid
where (i1.itemid = 1) or (i2.itemid = 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=daae80920212ae8a7c5ca9c24ea42dbc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show the attributes of the other linked item then just use a CASE WHEN clause and a WHERE IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE Itemid IN (

SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN ip.firstitemid = items.itemid THEN ip.seconditemid ELSE ip.firstitemid END as otherItem
FROM items
LEFT JOIN
    itempairs ip on items.itemid = ip.firstitemid or items.itemid = ip.seconditemid
WHERE itemid = '1' )
```

Or using a INNER JOIN With subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM  items T1 INNER JOIN (

SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN ip.firstitemid = items.itemid THEN ip.seconditemid ELSE ip.firstitemid END as otherItem
FROM items
LEFT JOIN
    itempairs ip on items.itemid = ip.firstitemid or items.itemid = ip.seconditemid
WHERE itemid = '1' ) as T2 INNER JOIN  ON T2.otherItem = T1.ItemID
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, although I probably should have clarified that I was trying to get attributes from both items, not just the paired one. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @melchiar it is not a problem. The other answer is what you are looking for. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ip.itemPairID         AS ip_itemPairID, 
       ip.firstItemID        AS ip_firstItemID, 
       ip.secondItemID       AS ip_secondItemID, 
       firstItem.attribute1  AS firstItem_attribute1, 
       firstItem.attribute2  AS firstItem_attribute2, 
       secondItem.attribute1 AS secondItem_attribute1, 
       secondItem.attribute2 AS secondItem_attribute2 
FROM   ItemPairs ip 
       INNER JOIN Items firstItem 
               ON firstItem.itemID = ip.firstItemID 
       INNER JOIN Items secondItem 
               ON secondItem.itemID = ip.secondItemID 
WHERE  ip.firstItemID = 1 
        OR ip.secondItemID = 1
```